# Cannot connect AngularJs app running on XAMP to API because of CORS error

Tags: angularjs, json, xampp

I've got an AngularJs app running which works with: https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos

But not with another API (can't show the link) which returns the error:

```
Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'APIURL' from origin 'http://localhost' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.

21:35:47.396 angular.js:12410 Cross-Origin Read Blocking (CORB) blocked cross-origin response APIURL. See https://www.chromestatus.com/feature/5629709824032768 for more details.
```

**Factory**

```
factory.readProducts = function(){
    return $http({
        method: 'GET',
        url: 'APIURL'
    });
    console.log('Factory read',factory.readProducts)

};
```

I've looked at multiple sources and can't come to a conclusion of how to solve this error. I'm running my app locally with XAMPP (or is there an alternative?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I needed to add `Access-Control-Allow-Origin: localhost` to my other servers `API` header

Comment: Could you not have posted hwo to do that, in order to help others?

Comment: Because it's dependant of your endpoint. Who ever serves the API end points should add them to their framework